# common elements in two Sylow p-subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

let $P_1$, $P_2$ be two different Sylow p-subgroups of $G$.

is this possible that non-identity element $a$ is in both $P_1$, $P_2$?

I thought this would be proved easily but I don't know even how to start.

hints or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this happens for example for $p=2$ in the group $S_4$ as can be seen either directly or by considering the number of elements in a product of two different $2$-Sylow subgroups.